# Is There A Way to Avoid Nested Switch Statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I am working on a React project using nested switch statements to route the user depending on their selection. The first case has two more nested switch statements. The second case has one nested switch statement. Is there another way I could do this without all the nested switch statements? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
clickConfirm = () => {
        switch (this.props.serviceType) {
            case 'car_service':
                switch (this.props.loadType) {
                    case 0: 
                        switch (this.props.photoMode) {
                            case 0:
                                this.props.push('/payment/');
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                this.props.push('/payment/');
                                // capture image here
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                this.props.push('/capture/');
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        switch (this.props.photoMode) {
                            case 0:
                                this.props.history.push('/address/');
                                this.props.setToPhoneNumber(false);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                this.props.history.push('/address/');
                                this.props.setToPhoneNumber(false);
                                // capture image here
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                this.props.push('/capture/');
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        this.props.history.push('/phone/');
                        this.props.setToPhoneNumber(true);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'phone_service':
                switch (this.props.photoMode) {
                    case 0:
                        this.props.history.push('/address/');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.props.history.push('/address/');
                        // capture image here
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        this.props.history.push('/capture/');
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data in an object like this:

```
const SERVICES = {
 'car_service': {
      0: {
          0: ()=> {
              this.props.push('/payment/');
           }
       }
  }
}
```

Then you can replace the `switch` part with:

```
clickConfirm = () => {
 SERVICES[this.props.serviceType][this.props.loadType][this.props.photoMode]();
}
```

Comment: This is very clean. If I moved SERVICES to a utility file, because the object might be large. How would I pass props? Would it be in 0: (props) => { props.history.push('/payment/');? Thank you for taking time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest this, seems like your component should maybe take in the option directly or otherwise be broken up instead of combined in the way it is.

But without knowing your use-case or why you're "pushing to props"(?), purely to "flatten" your condition, you could combine the various values and enumerate the known combinations.

NOTE: I haven't tested this or attempted to map this to your conditions exactly, but the general idea...

```js
const combined = [this.props.serviceType, this.props.photoMode, this.props.loadType || 'NA'].join('|');

switch (combined) {
    case 'car_service|0|0':
        this.props.push('/payment/'); break;
    case 'car_service|1|0':
        this.props.push('/payment/'); break; // capture image here
    case 'car_service|2|0':
        this.props.push('/capture/'); break;
    case 'car_service|0|1':
        this.props.push('/address/'); this.props.setToPhoneNumber(false); break;
    case 'car_service|1|1':
        this.props.push('/address/'); this.props.setToPhoneNumber(false); break;  // capture image here
    case 'car_service|2|1':
        this.props.push('/capture/'); break;
    case 'car_service|0|2':
    case 'car_service|1|2':
    case 'car_service|2|2':
        this.props.history.push('/phone/'); this.props.setToPhoneNumber(true); break;
    case 'phone_service|0|NA':
        this.props.history.push('/address/'); break;
    case 'phone_service|1|NA':
        this.props.history.push('/address/'); break; // capture image here
    case 'phone_service|2|NA':
        this.props.history.push('/address/'); break;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Looks like you took a good amount of time on it. I have never seen a switch statement like this. Flatten looks better than what I had. Thanks again.